# Setting up auto compile for Stylus

Tags: css, node.js, stylus

I have installed node.js/stylus/nib on my mac and I can manually compile `.styl` file to `.css` on the command line. I also know there is this `stylus.middleware()` things that keeps coming up when I search for how to setup auto-compiling when the `.styl` changes, however I have no idea how I am supposed to implement it (I have never used node.js before).

What file do I put that code in?

How do I start this code so it is always run?

I think I am missing a few things on the node side to be able to set this up.

Answer (score 27):

From the command line you can use:

```
stylus -w folder/
```

or just for another example:

```
stylus -w styl/*.styl -o css/
```

It will watch for changes and compile all *.styl files that live under that folder.

Comment: You can also list more than one folder from what I can tell testing it out.

Answer (score 9):

If you installed `stylus` as a global package (`npm install stylus -g`) you have a stylus binary on your system.

```
$ stylus -h
  Usage: stylus [options] [command] [< in [> out]]
                [file|dir ...]

  Commands:

    help [<type>:]<prop> Opens help info at MDC for <prop> in
                         your default browser. Optionally
                         searches other resources of <type>:
                         safari opera w3c ms caniuse quirksmode

  Options:

    -i, --interactive       Start interactive REPL
    -u, --use <path>        Utilize the stylus plugin at <path>
    -U, --inline            Utilize image inlining via data uri support
    -w, --watch             Watch file(s) for changes and re-compile
    -o, --out <dir>         Output to <dir> when passing files
    -C, --css <src> [dest]  Convert css input to stylus
    -I, --include <path>    Add <path> to lookup paths
    -c, --compress          Compress css output
    -d, --compare           Display input along with output
    -f, --firebug           Emits debug infos in the generated css that
                            can be used by the FireStylus Firebug plugin
    -l, --line-numbers      Emits comments in the generated css
                            indicating the corresponding stylus line
    --include-css           Include regular css on @import
    -V, --version           Display the version of stylus
    -h, --help              Display help information
```

Comment: unfortunately since -w does not support recursive watching, it is unless to me (and based on comments made here : https://github.com/LearnBoost/stylus/pull/227 : it is not going to happen)

Comment: sure, it seems to me like the ticket was resolved and closed 5 month ago. If not you could to to merge the pull request there into your own version of stylus.

Answer (score 6):

This briefly covers some Node basics.

**0. Organizing code.** It is a convention to put your main Node application code into a file called `app.js` in the project root.

Inside app.js things are grouped into two general parts:

1. **synchronous** initializations: require modules, build directories, read configs, db connections, etc. Things that block, so they must exist or die quickly.
2. **asynchronous** app tasks: start server, background processes, auto-compile CSS & JS, routing, i/o, etc. Things that are in the event loop.

**1. Compile Stylus to CSS when you build the app.** We need to require the [stylus](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stylus) module. Usually this is done at the top of the app.js to keep dependencies together.

```
var stylus = require('stylus');
```

The first time that Node runs `app.js`, you need this JS module to build your CSS. This is the basic idea:

```
stylus.render(stylus-code-string, function(err, css) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(css);
});
```

Here is the official [Stylus Javascript API](http://stylus-lang.com/docs/js.html).

To use the power of Node, you should read a stylus file using [fs module](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) into a buffer, then convert it to a string, and finally pass it into `stylus.render()`. Then, send the result into a destination file. Since this is part of the build process, it can be synchronous. But this is not really your question...

**2. Auto-compile CSS with Stylus as a background process.**

This function spawns a [child_process](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) that watches a single `.styl` file and compiles the included `.styl` files into a `.css` file. You do not need a module for this, only install the stylus executable so that it runs on the command line. (You have already done this). This example was made with stylus version **0.5.0**. Also, the folder paths that you use (ex. `build/styles` and `styles`) need to exist.

```
function watchStyles(sourcefile, destinationfolder) {
  var Stylus = child_process.spawn('stylus', ['--sourcemap', '-w', sourcefile, '--out', destinationfolder]);

  Stylus.stdout.pipe(process.stdout); // notifications: watching, compiled, generated.
  Stylus.stderr.pipe(process.stdout); // warnings: ParseError.

  Stylus.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log("Stylus process("+Stylus.pid+") error: "+err);
    console.log(err);
  });

  // Report unclean exit.
  Stylus.on('close', function (code) {
    if (code !== 0) {
      console.log("Stylus process("+Stylus.pid+") exited with code " + code);
    }
  });
}
```

Next, you need to call this function sometime after you start your app. Pass in your master `.styl` file as the source. Then the destination directory where you want your CSS to go.

```
// check that you passed '-w' parameter
if (process.argv[2] && (process.argv[2] == "-w")) {
  watchStyles('styles/app.styl', 'build/styles');
}
```

Start the app by running: 
`$ node app.js -w`

It helps to organize your `.styl` files under one `app.styl` so that the contents of your `app.styl` looks like this:

```
@import 'layout'
@import 'header'
@import 'main'
@import 'footer'
@import 'modal'
@import 'overrides'
```

Answer (score 2):

** *I end up here yesterday and didn't find the right answer. So this follow up is for anyone else who follows the same path as me...* **

I had a problem setting stylus command line up too. I kept trying to install `stylus` globally
`$ npm install -g stylus`
and would get errors. I had it working in one project with `grunt-contrib-stylus` but via command line I wasn't getting anything to work.
Even `$stylus --version` didn't return anything. I tried to update `npm` and it broke `npm`, so I ended up reinstalling `node` to reinstall `npm`. Then I was able to do a fresh install of `$ sudo npm install -g stylus` and could get the `--version`.
I also had to reinstall `grunt` and everything else I had installed globally via `npm`...

Answer (score 2):

First, install stylus locally `npm install stylus --save-dev` if you haven't.

Create a startup script that builds your stylesheet and rebuilds whenever change detected in your main stylus file:

**startup.js**

```
var fs = require('fs')
var stylus = require('stylus')

// Define input filename and output filename
var styleInput = __dirname + '/dev/stylus/main.styl'
var styleOutputFilename = 'main.css'
var styleOutput = __dirname + '/static/' + styleOutputFilename
var stylusPaths = [__dirname + '/dev/stylus', __dirname + '/dev/stylus/libs']

// Build stylesheet on first execute
buildStyles(styleInput, styleOutput, stylusPaths)

// Watch stylus file for changes.
fs.watch(styleInput, function(eventType, filename) {
  if (filename) {
    buildStyles(styleInput, styleOutput, stylusPaths)
  } else {
    console.log('no filename found. probably platform doesnt support it.');
  }
});

function buildStyles(input, output, paths) {
  stylus(fs.readFileSync(input, 'utf-8'))
    .set('paths', paths)
    .set('include css', true)
    .set('watch', true)
    .render(function(err, css) {
      if (err) throw err;

      fs.writeFile(output, css, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;

        console.log(' Stylesheet built successfully.');
      });
  });
}
```

Type `node startup.js` in the terminal. You will see a message "Stylesheet built successfully." whenever you change your main stylus file.

[There is good documentation about stylus javascript api in their website.](http://stylus-lang.com/docs/js.html)

Answer (score 0):

OK I edited my answer because you do not want to make a homepage and then connect-assets makes no sense and can not help you... but maybe this,...

http://thechangelog.com/post/3036532096/stylus-expressive-robust-feature-rich-css-language

on that site you find at the bottom a video which shows close to the end how to use stylus via command line...

HTH and sorry for the misunderstanding...

Comment: Ok, that part where is says "Then add this line to your app's configuration", what app configuration.  The only thing I need node.js for is to compile my stylus file.  My actually web application does not need node.js and I don't want to include node.js for my web application.