# What is the best way to use the "stylus" css preprocessor on Windows and Visual Studio?

Tags: windows

The "WebEssentials" Visual Studio Plugin only supports less, but I find the stylus syntax much more readable. Anybody uses it on Windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What do you mean on "supports"?

If just live watch and compress, there are few tools...

GIU:

- Mixture http://mixture.io/
- LiveReload http://livereload.com/ (beta!)

or use [node.js in console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10995330/setting-up-auto-compile-for-stylus) for autocompile.

Comment: as for me, i prefer powerful WebStorm IDE with build-in file watchers feature - http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2013/03/file-watchers-in-webstormphpstorm-6-a-k-a-background-tasks/

Comment: thx, wil take a look. As for "supports", it means just that: "supports". I assume you do not know the WebEssentials plugin, dont mind.

Comment: last time i tested LiveReload it was wery buggy ((

Comment: got it running with first live css edits. scripts not sure yet. now moving typescript, styuls generation out of visual studio to node.